# xmpp server to server

Tags: xmpp

Подскажите, как установить связь с xmpp сервером, заходить в конференции и посылать сообщения.

Я прошел TLS, посылаю сообщение:

```
 <stream:stream from='example.ru'      to='jabber.ru'      version='1.0'      xmlns='jabber:server'      xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
```

Получаю в ответ:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/strea
ms' xmlns='jabber:server' xmlns:db='jabber:server:dialback' id='1390742015' vers
ion='1.0'>

<stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='h
ttp://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='S4v2n+rKmTsgLFog7BtVvK2o660='/></st
ream:features>
```

И не понимаю, что делать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту "сообщения", вы послали не сообщение, а заголовок потока XMPP. И судя по ответу, связь вроде как успешно установлена.

Начиная с этого момента вы можете, собственно, посылать сообщения.

Comment: Какие сообщения? На сообщения типа <presence /> сервер ничего не отвечает.

Comment: А что, собственно, сервер должен ответить на это сообщение? Это же одностороннее уведомление.

Comment: Кстати, если вы используете s2s подключение, то сервер вам вообще ничего отвечать в нем не должен. Потому что обратные сообщения должны идти в обратном подключении.

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы устанавливаете соединение типа сервер-сервер, то, наверное, принимаете и входящие соединения от других серверов? Здесь jabber.ru ответил вашему серверу, что сейчас будет пытаться соединиться с сервером на указанном вами домене example.ru, с целью проверки, действительно ли ваш сервер уполномочен устанавливать соединения от имени домена example.ru. Пока не примете это входящее соединение (а сможете, только если записи в DNS для example.ru действительно указывают на ваш сервер, и он принимает входящие соединения), jabber.ru запросы обрабатывать не будет.
Подробности в [XEP-0220](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html).

Comment: Нет, ничего такого тут jabber.ru не ответил. Но, вероятно, и правда ждет начала шага 1 XEP-0220.

Comment: Настроил DNS, как-то не помогло.  Лог общения с jabber.ru: http://pastebin.com/z7f5Aaim

Comment: А входящее соединение от jabber.ru получаете? Должен прийти запрос dialback:verify, на который надо ответить. В XEP-0220 механизм подробно описан. Можно взять любой заведомо рабочий пакет с XMPP сервером (jabberd, CommuniGate) и посмотреть на реальный обмен в его отдаленных логах.